# How to replace divs in array using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I referred to the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/IlyaZ/gwj0t7zy/19/

I need to replace the first two divs (which have only `block` class) with other two divs (which have `s8-item-hidden` class).

Unfortunately, `replaceWith` does not work as I expected. For example, `shownBlocks[0].remove()` works fine.

Could you please advise how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shownBlocks[0]` returns a dom element reference which do not have [replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith) method which is provided by jQuery wrapper, you can use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method which return a jQuery wrapper reference to an element based on the passed index then call `replaceWith()`

```
$("#start").click(function () {
    var shownBlocks = $("div.block:not('.s8-item-hidden')");
    var hiddenBlocks = $("div.container > div.s8-item-hidden");

    shownBlocks.eq(0).replaceWith(hiddenBlocks[0]);
    shownBlocks.eq(1).replaceWith(hiddenBlocks[1]);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ncd8kzse/)

--

```
$("#start").click(function () {
    var shownBlocks = $("div.block:not('.s8-item-hidden')");
    var hiddenBlocks = $("div.container > div.s8-item-hidden");

    shownBlocks.replaceWith(function (i) {
        return $(hiddenBlocks).show();
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ncd8kzse/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the jquery wrapper around shownBlocks. could you see whether it works

```
$(shownBlocks[0]).replaceWith(hiddenBlocks[0]);
$(shownBlocks[1]).replaceWith(hiddenBlocks[1]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IlyaZ/gwj0t7zy/19/

I have modified your code little bit.

```
$("#start").click(function () {
    var shownBlocks = $("div.block:not('.s8-item-hidden')");
    var hiddenBlocks = $("div.container > div.s8-item-hidden");

    $(hiddenBlocks).each(function(index){
        $(shownBlocks[index]).replaceWith(this);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer

```
$(shownBlocks[0]).replaceWith(hiddenBlocks[0]);
$(shownBlocks[1]).replaceWith(hiddenBlocks[1]);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gwj0t7zy/22/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery:

```
$(selector).replaceWith(content)
```

Here is the fiddle with the code you provided.

http://jsfiddle.net/gwj0t7zy/21/

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if that's what you're looking for, but this works:

```
$("#start").click(function () {
    $(".block:not('.s8-item-hidden')").each(function(key, val){
        $(this).replaceWith($('.s8-item-hidden')[key]);
    });
});
```